# How to comparison array and pickup the same ~

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to compare:

1. NSMutableArray >ticket info (ticket name,time,date ,footage,ticket type ,price)
2. Show name

The ticket usually use normal ticket ,
but now I have some new Exclusive ticket ,
for example, I create a Easter egg show ,
this show only use Easter egg ticket, can not be use another ticket ,
so, I just want to display Easter egg ticket ,
but I don't know what show will added in future ,
so I want to comparison they, and added it to a new array ,
then I can use it to my picker!

Comment: array contains NSDictionaries or any object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following snippet filters array with `ticket type` and finds duplicate if any, its fastest approach then looping/iterating each element in array.

```
// *** Array of (NSDictionary)Tickets ***
NSMutableArray *arrTickets = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@{}, nil];
// *** Filter array by ticket type ***
NSPredicate *filterByTicketType = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ticket type == %@",@"EasterEggTicket"];
// *** Filtered Array ***
NSArray *filteredArray = [arrTickets filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filterByTicketType];
if([filteredArray count] > 0)
{
    // *** Duplicate Ticket Type Found ***
}
else
{
    // *** No Match Found, add one to array ***
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Fast Enumeration` for that

```
for(NSDictionary * currentTicket in ticketInfo)
{
    if([currentTicket objectForKey:@"ticketType"] isEqualToString:@"EasterEggTicket")
    {
        [easterTicketInfo addObject:currentTicket]
    }
}
```

where ticketInfo is the array of ticket details and easterTicketInfo is the new array you need to create.

I assumed your array contains NSDictionaries. If not use the proper way to access the object and its ticket type